# Create Current Month

Tags: date, ssas, mdx, olap, calculation

I want to create CurrentMonth for OLAP Cube (SSAS)
i have hierarchies "Calendar":

- yearID
- QuarterID
- MonthID
- DtDate

I've created CurrentYear
StrToMember("[Dates].[Calendar].[Year Id].&["+format(now(),"yyyy")+"]") <= active

and

CurrentMonth
StrToMember("[Dates].[Calendar].[Month Id].&[" + Format(now(), "MM") + "]") <= inactive

why CurrentMonth not active?

Maybe the problem is in the format?
StrToMember("[Dates].[Calendar].[Month Id].&[" + Format(now(), "m") + "]")? but this not active too

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the format 
in my table MonthID (yyyyMM)
Accordingly, the syntax should look like this
StrToMember("[Dates].[Calendar].[Month Id].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyyMM") + "]")